# MERN: show buttons based on conditional

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

I'm using React.JS and I'm trying to show a group of buttons based on the state of a variable, this is the code snippet:

```
  const cartContentButtons = (
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button> &&
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={orderHandler}>Order's Details</button>    
  );

  const orderDetailsButtons = (
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button> &&
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={orderHandler}>Cart's Content</button> &&    
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={orderHandler}>Order's Checkout</button>        
  );

  const modalActions = (
    <div className={classes.actions}>
      !isCheckout && hasItems ? cartContentButtons : orderDetailsButtons;
    </div>
  );
```

However, during code execution this is the result:

[image: showing buttons]

What am I missing to display the buttons properly?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please try: `{!isCheckout && hasItems ? cartContentButtons : orderDetailsButtons}`. In other words, enclose it within curly braces `{....}` and remove the semi-colon `;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must wrap your conditional statement in curly braces and remove the semicolon at the end.

```
<div className={classes.actions}>
  {!isCheckout &&
    hasItems ? cartContentButtons : orderDetailsButtons
  }
</div>
```

Look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, actually, it works adding curly brackets. However I found another bug: just the last button is displaying, if I remove the && operator I get this error: JSX expressions must have one parent element, any hints?

Comment: I think someone already answered your question. However, note that nested jsx expressions must always be wrapped in an element, like: 
    `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>  ==  <></>`
or
    `<div></div>`

We always render a single jsx element. React.Fragment is for not adding unnecessary div's, React renders nothing but all the elements in the nesting you set, without a parent perse.

Hint: Name your components with PascalCase.NB: Components (without children) are rendered in the form: <Component />

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include the brackets in your conditional, ever time you want to render something based on some logic or something that's not a component you should include it between brackets

```
  const cartContentButtons = (
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button> &&
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={orderHandler}>Order's Details</button>    
  );

  const orderDetailsButtons = (
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button> &&
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={orderHandler}>Cart's Content</button> &&    
    <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={orderHandler}>Order's Checkout</button>        
  );

  const modalActions = (
    <div className={classes.actions}>
      // include brackets here
      {!isCheckout && hasItems ? cartContentButtons : orderDetailsButtons}
    </div>
  );
```

take a look at [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) to know more about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, actually, adding curly brackets did the trick; also I found another bug during displaying buttons: just the last one shown, I took a suggestion from the IDE and I added JSX fragment: round the buttons with: <></>, should I avoid to use them or is it cool?

Comment: there's no problem using <></>, it's called react fragment and could be used in place of a div, take a look at [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)